# Cisco BGP Configuration

Tags: cisco, bgp

I need to configure a Cisco C1113 (router B) to enable BGP Routing between two networks.

I configured my router B, but I would need to make sure that my configuration is correct...

Here is the connexion I established:

```
         ASN 50624                      ASN 50600           (vlan2)
          ______                         ______            10.1.0.10
10.0.0.0 |      | 169.254.253.1         |      |           10.1.0.11
---------|   A  |-----------------------|  B   |---------- 10.1.0.14
         |______|         169.254.253.2 |______|           10.1.0.24

connexion between router A and B is done through a SFP Fiber
```

I would need to make sure that my 4 IPs from ASN 50600 are available over the network 10.0.0.0...

Here is the configuration I set:

for interfaces:

```
enable
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
interface vlan 2
ip address 10.1.0.10 255.255.255.0
description TS1
end
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/1
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
interface vlan 2
ip address 10.1.0.11 255.255.255.0
description TS 2
end
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/2
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
interface vlan 2
ip address 10.1.0.24 255.255.255.0
description H Preprod
end
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/3
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
interface vlan 2
ip address 10.1.0.14 255.255.255.0
description H Prod
end
```

and for BGP:

```
enable 
configure terminal
ip route 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0 null 0
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2
encapsulation dot1q 2
ip address 169.254.253.2 255.255.255.0
end
enable
configure terminal
router bgp 50600
redistribute connected
redistribute static
bgp router-id 169.254.253.2
bgp log-neighbor-changes
neighbor 169.254.253.1 remote-as 50624
network 10.1.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0
address-family ipv4 unicast
redistribute connected
neighbor 169.254.253.1 default-originate
neighbor 169.254.253.1 advertisement-interval 25
network 10.1.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0
neighbor 169.254.253.1 activate
exit-address-family
address-family ipv4 multicast
redistribute connected
neighbor 169.254.253.1 default-originate
neighbor 169.254.253.1 advertisement-interval 25
network 10.1.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0
neighbor 169.254.253.1 activate
exit-address-family
neighbor 192.254.253.1 activate
end
```

As I'm not familiar with BGP Protocol, if you can just help me to make sure that configuration is set correctly ?

Comment: Please show us the configuration from the `show running-config` command, not what you typed in. That will give us the how the router is actually configured. By the way, you cannot route link-local addresses in the `169.254.0.0/16` range. Routers are forbidden to route packets with either source or destination link-local addressing.

Comment: I have to disagree with @RonMaupin here.  While you are not supposed to advertise link local addresses, you can use them as you've done here.  In fact, this is exactly what the largest cloud provider, Amazon, requires you to do.

Comment: But please post the actual config as Ron requests.  The sample you show is missing some important info, and you have duplicated some configuration.

Comment: @RonTrunk, there is a difference. AWS completely goes against the RFC by allowing statically configured link-local addresses and subnetting the range. Cisco routers should be following the standard. IANA says that the link-local range is part of IPv4 (Reserved-by-Protocol).

Comment: Again, I must respectfully disagree.  While this use is not recommended by the RFC (See section 1.6), it is allowed  when *there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances when the particular behavior is acceptable or even useful.*

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a physical access tho this router right now, that's my main concer...I need to prepare everything to save time when I'll be on site...and concerning IP address, this is my provider who provides me the 169.254.0.0 IP addresses and BGP connexion is established correctly...but some servers are not available, this is the reason why I asked for confirmation on the sent commands....what are the information you need to check on show running-config ?

Comment: to be honest this is the only commands I run on the router, so the show running-config will not provide much more information I think... what are the other settings I need to update ?

Comment: The configuration of interface vlan 2 is incorrect.  The IP address of the interface will be used as the gateway for all hosts on the VLAN.

Comment: ok, so I need to change the vlan2 configuration for each interface ?

Comment: No. I think you misunderstand how this works.  The Vlan interface is just another interface on the VLAN.  The address of that interface (there is only one) is the gateway for devices on the VLAN.  In other words there is only one interface VLAN2, and it has only one IP address.

Comment: yes you're right I think I used the command "interface vlan2" in the incorrect way....I should delete those lines for each interface configuration isn't it ?

Comment: No.  There is only one interface.  You just overwrite it each time.

Comment: yes but I need to set the IP address of each GigabitEthernet port (considered as an interface) to reach my servers. Concerning the vlan2 I'll use another independent IP such as 10.1.0.30 out of the 4 IP of my servers, do you think this is ok ?

Comment: something like this: configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/3
ip address 10.1.0.14 255.255.255.0
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
description Prod
end
configure terminal
interface vlan2
ip address 10.1.0.30 255.255.255.0
end

Comment: No.  All the ports on VLAN 2 are layer 2 interfaces and do not have IP addresses.  The only interface that does is interface VLAN 2.

Comment: ok, so I just need to determine for each GigabitEthernet the vlan2 ownership and set a unique IP address for my vlan2 (10.1.0.30 for instance). independently from my router, my servers can be configured with a fixed IP (10.1.0.10,etc...) is that correct ? and sorry for the stupid questions....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135739/discussion-between-ron-trunk-and-tiamat).

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your config. It says 192 instead of 169. "neighbor 192.254.253.1 activate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interfaces configured as switchport do not have IP addresses.  The virtual interface (VLAN 2) has an IP address, and that is used as the default gateway for the hosts on the VLAN.